# Random Password Generator Keeps Generating the Same Password

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have to write a program that generates random passwords (using ASCII values and the chr() function) using Python and I have gotten my program to generate a random password, but when the program loops, it keeps printing the same random password and I have no idea what to do to fix it. If anyone could give me some advice, that would be great because I'm new to python

here is the code that I have so far:

```
import random, string

LNGTH=8
position=0
password=""
start=0
stop=0

while start==stop:
    input("would you like a password?")
    while position<LNGTH:
        x=random.randrange(9)
        character=chr(random.randrange(97, 97 + 26))
        choice=[str(x),character.upper(),character.lower()]
        pass_pos=random.choice(choice)
        password=password+pass_pos
        position+=1

    print(password)
```

Comment: Just to add that while you've had good answers to your question, you could've identified the problem by using a debugger and stepping through the code one line at a time. You'd instantly see that the `while` statement only ran once. The obvious next step is to examine the condition on the `while` when you would've seen `position` wasn't `0` as you expected. A debugger is a valuable tool and learning to use one can save you a lot of pain, especially in more complex code. Hope that helps for next time

Answer (score 2):

You never reset `position`, so your `while` loop always returns `True` after the first password is generated.

Because you also do not reset `password` that means you generate just the one random password and re-display that value over and over again.

You need to reset both *inside* the outer `while` loop:

```
while start==stop:
    input("would you like a password?")
    position = 0
    password = ''
```

You could just use `while True` instead of `start == stop` there. You could also use a `for` loop instead of your inner `while` loop, simplifying your setup:

```
password = ''
for i in range(LNGTH):
    x=random.randrange(9)
    character=chr(random.randrange(97, 97 + 26))
    choice=[str(x),character.upper(),character.lower()]
    pass_pos=random.choice(choice)
    password=password+pass_pos
```

Cleaning that up some more by using [`string.ascii_letters`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters) and [`string.digits`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.digits):

```
import string
import random

password_characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
length = 8

while True:
    if input("Would you like a password? ").lower() not in {'y', 'yes'}:
        break
    password = ''.join([random.choice(password_characters)
                        for _ in range(length)])
    print(password)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that makes a lot more sense XD

Answer (score 0):

Once you have been through the loop once, `position` is equal to `LNGTH`, so the loop `while position<LNGTH:` will exit immediately.

Set `position` back to zero and `password` back to `""` inside the outer loop

Answer (score 0):

Your code only generates one password and keeps printing it. That's because it runs the loop `while position < LNGTH` just once: inside the loop, you increase the position until the password is long enough. But during next iterations, `position` will be already long enough - so the `while` loop won't be entered; instead, the already previously generated password will be printed.

You have to reset `position` to zero before entering the `while` loop.

Answer (score -3):

At that point your program did everytime the same, so without initialising random you get everytime the same random.
you should use random.seed() first or even better use random.SystemRandom() if available.

Comment: That is not the problem.